# flutter StaggeredGridView show tiles on condition

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview

I am using **StaggeredGridView** in one of my Flutter project. I wanted to not load few **tiles** depending on the data availability.

For example. I am showing 5 tiles out of which 3 are dependent on the data available from network. Sometimes it may take 10 to 15 seconds. Right now if I return a Container() until my data gets loaded then also it holds the whole space in the layout.

I just don't want to add that tile to the grid if the data is not available or taking long to load. Once loaded it should be shown.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your `StaggeredGridView`, set the `staggeredTiles` property and make sure you pass in `StaggeredTile.fit(1)` for the tiles that you want to hide. This way the tile will wrap it's content so if there's not content it will be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<GridData>(
    stream: [Stream end point] // your stream url,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (!snapshot.hasData) return LoadingSpinner();
     return [View that you want to return]; // Your grid code.
   }
  )
}
```

Sample code